# PySpark Aggregate and When Condition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a question on PySpark.

```
df = (sc.parallelize([
    {"Day":1,"sensitive_id":"1234", "num":3},
    {"Day":1,"sensitive_id":"1234", "num":3}, 
    {"Day":2,"sensitive_id":"1234", "num":3},
    {"Day":3,"sensitive_id":"2345", "num":2},
    {"Day":3,"sensitive_id":"2345", "num":2},
    {"Day":3,"sensitive_id":"6789", "num":4},
    {"Day":4,"sensitive_id":"6789", "num":4},
    {"Day":4,"sensitive_id":"6789", "num":4},
    {"Day":4,"sensitive_id":"6789", "num":4}
 ]).toDF()
      )
```

[image]

I want to have a new column to have the corresponding "sensitive_id" as the max value of "num" column.

This is the result I have so far.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
(
    df 
    .withColumn(
        'top_sensitive_id',
        F.when
        (
            F.col('num') == F.max(F.col('num')).over(Window.partitionBy(F.col('Day'))),
            F.col('sensitive_id')
        )
    )
    .withColumn
    (
        'top',
        F.max(F.col('top_sensitive_id')).over(Window.partitionBy(F.col('Day')))
    )

    .show()
)
```

[image]

But I am sure there should be a more elegant and efficient way to do this.

Can someone provide a better way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are trying to do. Why are you using Window functions ? Can you please review the logic description ?

Comment: @eliasah Added a new column "Day". Hope this gives more clarity.

Comment: I’m sorry but this still doesn’t clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost close to best approach, But I still tried to add few things -

1.Calculate 'top' once and use same for comparison.

2.Use separate column definition, it will help in better readability
   and maintainability

```
 from pyspark.sql.window import Window

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy('Day')
top = max('sensitive_id').over(windowSpec).alias('top')

df.select('Day','Num','sensitive_id',top).withColumn('top_sensitive_id', expr("CASE WHEN sensitive_id = top THEN top END")).show()
```